# If $\mathbb E[X]$ is increasing in $\theta$, is $\mathbb E[X^2]$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, monotone-functions

Consider a discrete random variable $X\in[0,1]$ with p.m.f. $f_X(x)$ parametrized by $\theta$.
Assume its expected value $\mathbb E[X]$ is increasing in $\theta$.

Is $\mathbb E[X^2]$ increasing in $\theta$ as well?

The equality $\mathbb E[X^2] = \mathbb E[X]^2+Var(X)$ shows that a sufficient condition is for the derivative w.r.t. $\theta$ of $\mathbb E[X]^2+Var(X)$ to be positive. Is there a reason this should be true in general?

Comment: What do you mean by discrete random variable in $[0, 1]$? Do you mean the discrete set $\{0, 1\}$, or the continuous range $[0, 1]$? Note that if it's the discrete set, then $X^2=X$.

Comment: @TodorMarkov It is discrete but it takes values in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: What is $\theta$? A parameter of the distribution?

Comment: @MPW Yes. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: It is not necessarily increasing, this conclusion should also hold in the continuous variable case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ take the values $\theta$ and $1-\theta$ with probabilities $\frac 3 4$ and $\frac 1 4$ respectively. You can verify that $EX$ is an increasing function of the parameter $\theta$ on $[0,1]$ but $EX^{2}$ is increasing for $\theta >\frac 1 4$, decreasing for $\theta <\frac 1 4$.

Comment: OK, that settles it for the general case. Any ideas on where to look to figure out which variables might satisfy this?